# How can I check if current selected camera has image plane or not?

Tags: python, maya

This code works only when the selected camera has the image plane.

So I would like to make it pop up window saying to add image plane first when the camera doesn't have image plane.

But how can I check if current selected camera has image plane or not?

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
c = cmds.ls(sl=True,dag=True,s=True)
cmds.setAttr((c[0] + 
'.nearClipPlane'), 0.5)
cmds.setAttr((c[0] + '.farClipPlane'), 10000000)
ip = cmds.listConnections(c[0], type="imagePlane")
cmds.setAttr((ip[0] + '.depth'), 80000)
```

Comment: I am not at all a maya expert, but for what I have read on the web, the image plane is actually _calculated_, and not extracted from the image as if the image would already have the image plane object. Just willing to help. Am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To check if the `imagePlane` exists, you can do

```
import maya.cmds as MC
connection = MC.listConnections('perspShape.imagePlane', type='imagePlane', et=True)
if not connection:
    print("No ImagePlane set")
```

A headsup on the arguments passed in to `listConnections`

```
et (exactType) only considers the exact given type and ignores derived ones
```